# How to force clang-format to put array initialization on one line within a class instantiation?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I can't manage to make clang-format to put a array initialisation withing a class instantiation on a single line.

I have this basic code :

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::map<int, std::list<std::string>>& b);
}
```

I want this bit of code to be formated like:

```
void
test()
{
    Foo f({1, 2, 3},
          {{0, {"toto"}}});
}
```

But instead clang-format is formating it like that:

```
void
test()
{
    Foo f({
              1, 2, 3
    },
          {{0, {"toto"}}});
}
```

I feel that it's maybe clang that is getting lost because of all the brakets. Indeed, this bit of code is well formated

```
void
test()
{
    Foo f({1, 2, 3},
          {0, {"toto"}});
}
```

My clang-format :

```
---
Language: Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping: # not used if BreakBeforeBraces is not set to Custom
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 0
CommentPragmas: "^ IWYU pragma:"
QualifierAlignment: Left
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
PackConstructorInitializers: BinPack
BasedOnStyle: ""
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks: Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority: 2
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority: 3
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: ".*"
    Priority: 1
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
IncludeIsMainRegex: "(Test)?$"
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ""
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentCaseBlocks: true
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
MacroBlockBegin: ""
MacroBlockEnd: ""
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PointerAlignment: Left
PPIndentWidth: -1
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments: true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes: CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros: true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard: Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth: 4
UseCRLF: false
UseTab: Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
...
```

Comment: You may want to try using the clang-format configurator: https://clang-format-configurator.site/

Comment: btw there is no array.